# How to add description to Django command?

Tags: python, django, command-line

In [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html), the description is passed into the `ArgumentParser` constructor like so:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Print a number")
parser.add_argument('-n', dest='number', action='store', type=str, 
                    help="The number to be printed")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

When doing a similar thing using a Django command, how does one add the `description="Print a number"` given that the `ArgumentParser` has already been constructed?

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand


class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):

        parser.add_argument('-n', dest='number', action='store', type=str,
                            help="The number to be printed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set its [`help` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.help):

> **`BaseCommand.help`**
>
> A short description of the command, which will be printed in the help message when the user runs the command `python manage.py help <command>`.

For example:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Command description'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        # ...
```